# `UIBezierPath.fill()` does not fill inside of `draw()`

Tags: uiview, uikit, core-graphics

I'm cutting a rectangle out of a semi-transparent `UIView`. When I use `UIRectFill()` it works as expected. However when I create a `UIBezierPath` with rounded corners, `fill()` does not seem to do anything. Oddly, calling `stroke()` on that same path works fine.

**WORKS:**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    screenColor.set()
    UIRectFill(self.bounds)

    let viewfinderRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)

    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    UIRectFill(viewfinderRect)  //Works!
}
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    screenColor.set()
    UIRectFill(self.bounds)

    let viewfinderRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewFinderRect, cornerRadius:  10.0)

    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    path.fill()             // Does not work!
    //path.stroke()         // Works!
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not drawing with the same [blend mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-BCIGICEF).

The [documentation for `UIRectFill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623932-uirectfill) says:

> Fills the specified rectangle using the fill color of the current graphics context and the kCGBlendModeCopy blend mode.

(In Swift, the name for this blend mode is [`CGBlendMode.copy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgblendmode).)

When you use this blend mode, the specified fill color is copied into the context, *replacing* whatever was underneath. Since your fill color is clear, you effectively cut a hole in the view.

However, when you call `path.fill()`, it uses the default blend mode in the context, which is `CGBlendMode.normal`. That draws the fill color *over* whatever was already in the context. Since your fill color is clear, that has no visible effect.

Try this:

```
UIColor.clear.setFill()
path.fill(with: CGBlendMode.copy, alpha: 1.0)
```

Or this:

```
UIColor.clear.setFill()
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.copy)
path.fill()
```

Or you can even do it in one line:

```
path.fill(with: CGBlendMode.clear, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: the one liner didn't worked, but the previous 3 worked. thank you so much!